# large, multi-dc cassandra deployment in ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra

Our current cassandra cluster is 26 nodes spread across four AWS EC2 regions. We use elastic IP's for all of our nodes, and we use security groups to allow all nodes to talk to each other.

There is a hard limit of 250 security group rules per network interface (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Appendix_Limits.html#vpc-limits-security-groups). From the documentation:

> You can have 50 inbound and 50 outbound rules per security group (giving a total of 100 combined inbound and outbound rules). If you need to increase or decrease this limit, you can contact AWS Support — a limit change applies to both inbound and outbound rules. However, the multiple of the limit for inbound or outbound rules per security group and the limit for security groups per network interface cannot exceed 250

Since each node needs a security group entry for every other node in the cluster, that means we have a hard limit of a 250 node cluster.

I can think of some ways to mitigate the issue, like using two security groups, where one allows access from the 'local' nodes in the same region, and the other security group has the elastic IP's for the 'remote' nodes in other regions. This would help, but only a little bit.

I have been in touch with AWS technical support about this, and they suggested using contiguous blocks of elastic IP's (which I did not know was possible). This seems like it would solve the problem, but it turns out this is an involved process, and requires us (my company) to become the ARIN owner of these IP's. The AWS reps are pushing me towards alternatives, such as DynamoDB. I am open to other technologies to solve our problem, but I get the feeling they are just trying to get us to use AWS managed services. On top of that they are rather slow in getting back to me when I ask questions like "Is this typically how customers run multi region cassandra clusters in ec2?"

Does anyone have experience with this approach?

What are some alternatives to using security groups? Does anyone have experience running a large (>250 node), multi region cassandra cluster in EC2? Or even a cluster with >50 nodes (at which point a single security group isn't feasible any more)?

Comment: I think you need to do something like what is described in this blog post to link your VPCs together: http://fortycloud.com/interconnecting-two-aws-vpc-regions/ then you would be able to use internal VPC IP ranges and not need public Elastic IPs.

Comment: Why do your Cassandras have elastic IPs? What is the need? To access internet or to communicate with other nodes in your account? Based on your answer, I can suggest some network modifications to solve your problem.

Comment: @helloV the nodes have elastic ips so that we can have security group rules to let them talk to each other without exposing their ports to the world